# How to add control dependency to Tensorflow op

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want `update_op` to run before I run `summary`. Sometimes I just create a `tf.summary`, and everything works just fine, but sometimes I want to do more fancy stuff, but still have the same control dependency.

Code that doesn't work:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    if condition:
        tf.summary.scalar('summary', summary)
    else:
        summary = summary
```

Bad hack that works

```
with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    if condition:
        tf.summary.scalar('summary', summary)
    else:
        summary += 0
```

The problem is that `summary=summary` doesn't create a new node, so the control dependency is ignored.

---

I am sure that there is a way better way of going about this, any suggestions? :-)

Comment: Does `tf.identity(summary)` work?

Comment: Using `summary =tf.identity(summary)` works, but it is quite similar to the current implementation. I was hoping for an even nicer solution, but as is it is the best I have :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there exists a more elegant solution to this, because this the designed behavior. [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) is a shortcut of [`tf.Graph.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies) call using a default graph, and here's the quote from its documentation:

> N.B. The control dependencies context applies only to ops that are
>   constructed within the context. Merely using an op or tensor in the
>   context does not add a control dependency. The following example
>   illustrates this point:
>
> ```
> # WRONG
> def my_func(pred, tensor):
>   t = tf.matmul(tensor, tensor)
>   with tf.control_dependencies([pred]):
>     # The matmul op is created outside the context, so no control
>     # dependency will be added.
>     return t
>
> # RIGHT
> def my_func(pred, tensor):
>   with tf.control_dependencies([pred]):
>     # The matmul op is created in the context, so a control dependency
>     # will be added.
>     return tf.matmul(tensor, tensor)
> ```

So just use `tf.identity(summary)`, as suggested in the comments.