# Tensorflow: what is the difference between tf.identity and '=' operator

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I'm confused about `'='` operator, and `tf.identity()`, I thought `'='` is to just make a reference of the tensor, and identity is to make a copy, e.g., with

```
ref = x
ref = ref*0
sess.run(x)
```

I will get `x` all been set to 0 element-wise, and with

```
copy = tf.identity(x)
copy = ref*0
sess.run(x)
```

`x` would not be changed, since identity make copy, not a reference, but with experiment, `'='` also make a copy and `x` is not set to 0, so what's the  difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is only in tensorlfow graph layout. [`tf.identity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity) creates a *new op* in the graph that mimics its argument, while pure assignment adds a *new python variable* that points to the same op.

In both cases (the pair `ref` and `x` or the pair `copy` and `x`), both ops always evaluate to the same value. But in the second case, `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()` will reveal a new operation in the list called `Identity`.

```py
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.Variable(1.0)
sess.run(x.initializer)

ref = x
copy = tf.identity(x)
print(x.eval(), copy.eval(), ref.eval())  # 1.0 1.0 1.0

sess.run(x.assign(2.0))
print(x.eval(), copy.eval(), ref.eval())  # 2.0 2.0 2.0

print(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations())
```

You may wonder, why would anyone want to introduce a new op when she can simply make an assignment. There cases when assignment doesn't work, but `tf.identity` does, exactly because it creates a new op, e.g. in control flow. See this question: [How to add control dependency to Tensorflow op](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46813667/712995).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to be correct anymore, at least with eager execution. `tf.identity` will return a different tensor with the same values, so it is equivalent to `<variable>.read_value()`. Here is an example from the documentation, showing the current behavior:

```
a = tf.Variable(5)
a_identity = tf.identity(a)
a.assign_add(1)

a.numpy() # 6 

a_identity.numpy() # 5
```

Thus, we see that ops performed on a tensor returned by `tf.identity` do not affect the tensor on which it was called.