# Tensorflow - Copy Tensor vs. Assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

What is the correct way to make a copy of a Tensorflow tensor? In regular Python, assignment of non-primitives (`b = a`) creates a reference to the same object, so we use deepcopy. Is `tf.identity` similarly required in Tensorflow, or does Tensorflow consider `b` a unique Tensor after `b = a`?

My specific need is summarized below. I am building a model in blocks, and each block takes the output of the previous block, feeds it through layers, and then sums with the original raw output of the previous block. See the 2 lines marked as method A and method B. Which is correct?

```
for block_num in range(4):

    if block_num == 0:
        x = inputTensor

    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)

    if block_num > 0:
        x = block_output_tensor + x

    # method A - assignment
    block_output_tensor = x

    # method B - copy
    # block_output_tensor = tf.identity(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case simple assignment `block_output_tensor = x` should work fine. Just reorder the lines, to define `block_output_tensor` before its use.

However in some more complex situations, it is important to ensure proper graph layout with use of `tf.identity()`. See this matter discussed [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173854/tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-tf-identity-and-operator#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20is%20only%20in,points%20to%20the%20same%20op.&text=identity%20does%2C%20exactly%20because%20it,op%2C%20e.g.%20in%20control%20flow.).